# Powershell scripting methodargumentconversioninvalidargument

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie to Powershell scripting and I want to find the standard deviation of the numbers I have in the results variable.

Following is my code:

```
param(

    ## The command to measure
    [Scriptblock] $Scriptblock,

    ## The number of times to measure the command's performance
    [int] $Iterations = 2
)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

## Figure out how many extra iterations we need to account for the outliers
$buffer = [int] ($iterations * 0.1)
$totalIterations = $iterations + (2 * $buffer)

## Get the results
$results = 1..$totalIterations |
    Foreach-Object { Measure-Command $scriptblock }

## Sort the results, and skip the outliers
$middleResults = $results | Sort TotalMilliseconds |
    Select -Skip $buffer -First $iterations

$popdev = 0            

## Show the average
$avg = $results | Measure-Object -Average | select Count, Average    
$middleResults | Measure-Object -Average TotalMilliseconds  
foreach ($number in $results){            
  $popdev +=  [math]::pow(($number - $avg.Average), 2)            
}
```

I get the following error:

Count    : 2
Average  : 351.1846
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : TotalMilliseconds

Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "op_Subtraction" to type "System.TimeSpan": "Cannot convert null to
type "System.TimeSpan"."
At C:\script.ps1:55 char:3
+   $popdev +=  [math]::pow(($number - $avg.Average), 2)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem that I see (which is where the error is coming from) is that `$results` is a collection of Timespan objects (because that's what `measure-command` outputs).

Second, you didn't specify what property to Average when dealing with `$middleresults`.

Third, you didn't assign the pipeline starting with `$middleresults` to anything, so it is simply output.  I'm not sure what you want to do with this result.

Because `$results` are Timespan objects, inside the `pow` function, when you use `$number` by itself you get an error subtracting the averages.  If you use `$number.TotalMilliseconds`, I think you'll get what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks adding "$number.TotalMilliseconds" worked well and also changed this line "$avg = $results | Measure-Object -Average TotalMilliseconds | select Count, Average " I wanted to get mean and standard deviation for the $results